# jsx-a117 lint error "the autocomplete attribute is incorrectly formatted"

Tags: accessibility

After updating my project to react-scripts v4 I started receiving lint errors of this type:

```
the autocomplete attribute is incorrectly formatted jsx-a11y/autocomplete-valid
```

```
<input
    type="text"
    autoComplete="first-name"
/>
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value used in the autocomplete attribute (`first-name`) is not a valid value.

This means no semantic meaning is given to this input and tools that auto-fill forms may not correctly fill the input with pre-saved values.

`given-name` is the correct value for this input:

```
<input
    type="text"
    autoComplete="given-name"
/>
```

All valid values can be found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values

Comment: I really need to start self answering, really useful way to keep track of stuff that I learn and then forget the next day :-P.